# How to create indices for icosahedronbuffergeometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a trouble and don't know how to resolve or manage the situation.
I just want an alternative texturing sphere instead of using spherebuffergeometry in three.js i want to use icosahedronbuffergeometry with some addition code to generate indices since my render using drawelement instead drawarray. However the result is not as per expected, see link below.

The modification are on PolyhedronBufferGeometry function as follow:

```
 1. var idx = []; // line 24097
 2. this.setIndex( new ( Uint16Attribute )( idx, 1 ) ); // line 24119
 3. var iv = []; // line 24157 to store temp indices
 4. var iCount = idx.length; // line 24157
 5. iv[ i ][ j ] = ij ; ij++; // in the loop in line 24174
 6. idx.push( iCount+ iv[ i ][ k + 1 ]); // in the loop in line 24194
```

Here is the result using modified icosahedronbuffergeometry 
[icosahedron texturing](http://eksame.com/webgl/moonphase.080117/)

While using spherebuffergeometry is as below
[sphere buffer texturing](http://eksame.com/webgl/moonphase.281216/)

Answer (score 0):

After doing an analysis within a few days, i know that some of additional code are wrong. I understand now that vertex buffer position are copied multiple times to set triangles thus the indices or index is not need to be created. Indices can be created by just replacing the code no. 6 above with

```
 6. idx.push( idx.length + counter); // in the loop in line 24194
```

code no. 3 to no. 5 is not needed anymore. The result can be seen on the link above with no more missing triangles faces.

I think the code on PolyhedronBufferGeometry can be recreated to be more efficient.